# What should int() and real() of a space string be in gnuplot?

Tags: floating-point, integer, gnuplot, nan

The gnuplot functions `int()` and `real()` try to convert a number or string into an integer or floating point number, respectively. Apparently, either they succeed or they give an error.

For example, if I have an empty string `''`, `int()` and `real()` will give an error:

```
Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

That's ok.
However, if I have a string constisting out of one or multiple spaces `int()` and `real()` will return `0` and `0.0`, respectively.

**Question:** how to tell gnuplot that an empty string is basically *not `0`* but instead "not a number" `NaN`?

I could write a function checking if a string consists only out of spaces and then either return `NaN` or the non-"only-space" string.

However, while trying this, I also noticed that

- `print real(NaN)` will return `NaN`
- `print int(NaN)` will give an error `undefined value`.

Seems like I have to check for `NaN` as well.

**Script:**

```
### space string is converted to 0
reset session

array A = [ 1, 1.2, "1.3", " 1.4", "1.x", " ", "  "]
print A

do for [i=1:7] { print A[i], "   ", real(A[i]) }
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
[1,1.2,"1.3"," 1.4","1.x"," ","  ",""]

1   1.0
1.2   1.2
1.3   1.3
 1.4   1.4
1.x   1.0
    0.0
     0.0
```

Comment: Note that NaN is represented by a defined bit pattern stored in an IEEE floating point value.  See `man NaN`. There is no equivalent definition for an integer value, so int(foo) cannot return NaN because NaN is not representable as an integer.

Comment: @Ethan thank you for your explanation, learned again something. I'm still trying to tell gnuplot that `' '` should not be `0`, but it seems I am missing a function like `isNumber()` or `isString()` to differentiate between numbers and strings.

Comment: I'm still thinking about the issue of blank strings being converted to 0. This arises from the underlying use of standard C functions atof() and atoll(), which do not distinguish between "evaluates to zero" and "produces an error".  There is an alternative function strtod() that does claim to return error status separately, but I don't think there is any cross-platform guarantee that a blank string is considered an error in that sense. So gnuplot would, I think, have to test separately for blank strings if that is to be considered an error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising these issues regarding promotion of a string to a numeric value when gnuplot encounters it while evaluating an expression.

I submitted this as a bug report to the gnuplot issue tracker. Please see an expanded list of problematic cases and a pending fix to appear in the next release version.
[Bug #2527](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2527/)